# Como poner texto al lado derecho de un input de forma centrada verticalmente?

Tags: bootstrap-4

estoy validando un input, y al hacerlo, cuando los valores ingresados no son validos se muestra una alerta(hasta ahí todo bien). Sin embargo estéticamente no se ve muy bien, por lo que quería saber si es posible alinear el texto mostrado para que quede mas centrado de forma vertical con el input a su lado, dejare una imagen para que se entienda mejor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Rut</label>
       <input class="form-control" name="rut" id="rut" type="text">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="hide" id="msg_rut" style="color:red;">Rut Invalido</span>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

También estoy abierto a sugerencias de como mostrar una alerta de este tipo de forma mas estética para los usuarios, si tienen una sugerencia se los agradecería

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu span necesita un pequeño ajuste con css, debe quedar así:

```
<span class="hide" id="msg_rut" style="color:red;position: absolute;margin-top: 30px;">Rut Invalido</span>
```

Comment: Gracias socio :D